# Can't manage to use Substring()

Tags: c#, substring

I'm trying to use `Substring` to split the line below

```
MARAMBIO                MBI  VORD-64.235000 -56.620278117.00H
```

as

- MARAMBIO
- MBI
- VORD
- -64.235000
- -56.620278
- 117.00H

for the first two words my code is:

```
string firstPart = lines[17].Substring(0, 23); 
string secondPart = lines[17].Substring(24, 27);
```

output for string firsPart is correct however

secondPart gives me `MBI  VORD-64.235000 -56.6202` as I was expecting only `MBI` as they are the 24,25,26 and 27th.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Next time at least spend 10 seconds [reading the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) before asking a questioin please.

Comment: First thing to do is to read the documentation :). Search on [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.aspx) for [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter in [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) is for number of elements not index of ending character.

```
string secondPart = lines[17].Substring(24, 3);
```

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and has a specified length.

#### Syntax

```
public string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
```

*startIndex*

```
Type: System.Int32
The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.
```

*length*

```
Type: System.Int32
The number of characters in the substring.
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is length, not end.  Change it to `string secondPart = lines[17].Substring(24, 3);`